# Use dynamic reconfiguration to set the parameter value in ROS

Tags: dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS and i want to use Dynamic reconfiguration technique to set a parameter (`rectangle_height`).

Through internet i came across with the following method but its not working.

**Problem:** when i run `rqt_reconfigure`, in that my node (visual_analysis) is not visual so i can't change the parameter.

-In my **Includes**, i have included the following:

```
#include <dynamic_reconfigure/DoubleParameter.h>
#include <dynamic_reconfigure/Reconfigure.h>
#include <dynamic_reconfigure/Config.h>
```

-In my **`main()`** where my variable is declared, i have written the following:

```
int main( )
{
    double rectangle_height;
    
    ///////////////////Dynamic Reconfig
    dynamic_reconfigure::ReconfigureRequest srv_req;
    dynamic_reconfigure::ReconfigureResponse srv_resp;
    dynamic_reconfigure::DoubleParameter double_param;
    dynamic_reconfigure::Config conf;   
    
    //Entering values using Dynamic Reconfig
    double_param.name = "kurtana_pitch_joint";
    double_param.value = rectangle_height;
    conf.doubles.push_back(double_param);
    
    srv_req.config = conf;
    ros::service::call("/visual_analysis/set_parameters", srv_req, srv_resp);
    
        
    return 0; 
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/132666/use-dynamic-reconfiguration-to-set-the-parameter-value-in-ros/) by [rosqueries](https://answers.ros.org/users/6415/rosqueries/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to add explicit support for dynamic_reconfigure in the node you're trying to configure.

Dynamic_reconfigure has a very nice tutorial describing how to do this: http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/SettingUpDynamicReconfigureForANode%28cpp%29

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0